# Postman POST request returning None in django

Tags: django, http, post, request, postman

I'm trying to send POST requests using postman to an API in a django server. The API is an APIView :

```py
class LoginView(APIView):
    
    template_name = 'login.html'
    from_class = LoginForm  

    def post(self, request, format=None):
       
        data = request.data
        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        print(username)
```

and here is the postman request in the joint image[image]

The problem is I'm always getting None username and password.
Please if you can spot the problem can you guide me.

Comment: try this: change data.get to request.POST.get()

Comment: @ming it gives None too.

Comment: you are sending the data as query params, so you should access `request.query_params` instead of `request.data`. I would suggest you sending the sensitive data in the body of your reqest and then you will be able to access it via `request.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ersain has pointed out in the comments, you are using query parameters in Postman.

You need to navigate to the body tab in Postman, select raw, then select JSON. You can then type in the username and the password.

[image: How to add data to the body of a request using postman]